# How to tile windows without going into full screen?

Tags: mac, display, window-manager

Currently, if I want to tile two instances, I press the green button on the top-left and place the instance accordingly.

However, each of the tiled instances always go into full screen mode. For a chrome instance, this is annoying as it means it's not possible to see the tabs.

How do I tile windows without making them go  full screen?

Answer (score 17):

Pressing the green traffic light button would cause the window of most macOS apps to go full-screen.

You can press and hold the <kbd>Option</kbd> key when clicking on the green traffic light button to prevent the window from going into full-screen mode.

If you want to tile and align various windows belonging to same of different apps, you can use one of the many 3rd party window and tiling manager apps.

One such app that I use and find very useful is [Divvy - Window Manager](https://apps.apple.com/app/divvy-window-manager/id413857545). It lets you tile windows quickly and efficiently for any macOS app and supports multiple displays too.

**P.S.**: No affiliation whatsoever with the developer of the app. Just a satisfied customer.

Comment: the app suggestion is great - the `option` solution doesn't seem to work on my mac though :( I'm on mojave 10.14.5

Comment: There are several other third party applications that also accomplish this if the one mentioned is insufficient. A quick internet search for "Tiling Window Manager for MacOS" will yield a bunch of alternatives. I use "BetterTouchTool" which has tiling functionality but is also paid - there are many FOSS alternatives that don't require $$. An example of FOSS alternative would be the app "Spectacle" and it's derivatives/descendants

Comment: Divvy is not free

Comment: Baffling how such a simple and basic productivity feature is so hard on Mac

Answer (score 11):

If you press the <kbd>Option</kbd> button, then open the Window menu, you will the see that `Tile Window to Left of Screen` will now read `Move Window to Left Side of Screen`.

To make this easier, I mapped keyboard shortcuts for <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> and <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> to do this.

Once you map these shortcuts, these options will show up in the Window menu permanently without needing to press the <kbd>Option</kbd> key

Comment: Weirdly, setting up a shortcut like this works for Chrome windows but not Adobe Reader windows!?  "Move Window to Left Side of Screen" appears in the menu for Chrome (as well as tile) but only when I press the "Option" button for Adobe.. Any idea why??

Answer (score 7):

The best option for me was to create keyboard shortcuts. You will need to use the exact text for it to work.

**Under:** `System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts > +`

Add the following 'Menu Title' shortcuts to whatever key combination you prefer.

e.g. I used <kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd> + <kbd>⌃ CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>

**Menu Titles:**

- `Zoom` - resizes window to fill screen, without going "fullscreen".
- `Move Window to Left Side of Screen` - resizes window to the left 50% of the screen (no tiling).
- `Move Window to Right Side of Screen` - resizes window to the right 50% of the screen (no tiling).

Comment: this still does it in full screen

Answer (score 1):

[Rectangle](https://rectangleapp.com/) will let you do this by keyboard shortcut ($0).

[Moom](https://manytricks.com/moom/) will actually modify those buttons for you *and* give you keyboard shortcuts *and* customizations *and* more. Highly recommended. $10, but there's a free trial at the link.